# Jade anchor under paragraph

Tags: html, pug

hello I am new to jade and I'm wondering how can I fix this I'm not sure if its an error

```
p foo bar hello world
a link
```

formats this

```
<p>foo bar hello world</p><a></a>
```

I want this:

```
<p>foo bar hello world</p>
<a>link</a>
```

Comment: try a=link. If my memory serve me right....
Also, Jade now named Pug ;)

Comment: Why do you care if the HTML has a new line in the source code there? It doesn't change the meaning of the HTML at all.

Comment: :C sorry I am a noob at programming I thought it was an error

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the workflow you're using you can prettify your html output to make it more readable for you. Especially as you say you're a beginner, it could be helpful to see the output in a more readable form as opposed to inline like this. If you tell me your workflow I could show you how to do that